# Overflow error when reading json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter, tweets

I am trying to read a json which includes a number of tweets, but I get the following error.

OverflowError: int too large to convert

The script filters multiple json files to get specific tweets, and it crashes when reaching to a specific json.

The line that creates the error is this one :

```
df_temp = pd.read_json(path_or_buf=json_path, lines=True)
```

[Here is the error in the cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Reen7.png)

Comment: `json.loads('{"id":73115419563449548887439843987598743985743234857632498756324987563248756238987432659874365987324655}')` works fine for me. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve]? Because, to the best of my knowledge, with the default settings, recentish Python (as in from at least 2.7 and 3.3, maybe earlier) will load `731154195634495488` as an `int`, not a `float`.

Comment: That's true. Most probably the id has nothing to do with the error. Essentially, my script filters multiple json files to get specific tweets, and it crashes when reaching to a specific json. The line that creates the error is this one : 

`df_temp = pd.read_json(path_or_buf=json_path, lines=True, dtype={"id_str": np.float64}`

Comment: Can you give us sample JSON which causes the error?

Comment: Sure. You can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FefPOdCir5fFpdTU8H78SFkSrNiZCTMw)

Comment: That doesn't produce an error for me: https://repl.it/repls/TraumaticMidnightbluePort

Comment: When running the script for specifically this json, it does not occur. The error occurs after running on a few jsons. I thought that this json produces the error, because the script crashes always on this one, but seemingly it has to do with something else. If possible, check the cmd error as well (linked in the question above)

Answer (score 0):

Just store the user id as a String, and treat it like it is one (this is actually what you should do when dealing with this kind of ids). If you can't change the json input format, you can always parse it like a string before parsing it like a json object, and add the quotes to the id code, using for instance regexes: [Regex in python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

I don't know with which library you are parsing the json, but maybe also implicit casting will work: either try the "getString" method on the number instead of the "getInt" method, or force python to treat the object like a string, with something like `x = "" + json.getId()`

Python is pretty loose on typing and may let you do it.

Comment: After further testing, it seems that the id has nothing to do with the error. I still do not know what may cause it though.